# How to initialize vector of object with constructor call explicite?

Tags: c++, class, vector, initialization

In the following example I try to create a different object with each constructor call. I wonder how to do it by calling the constructor explicitly?

```
class A {
public:
    static int count;
    int num;
    A() { num = ++count; }
};

int A::count = 0;

main() {
    vector<A> x(5, A());  // all A.num values == 1
    vector<A> y(5);       // A.num values == 2,3,4,5,6 but no explicit constructor call
}
```

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you need to solve? Why do you need to call the constructor explicitly?

Comment: Why does calling constructor explicitly, makes `A.num = 1` for all 5 objects? Why isn't `num` getting incremented via static variable `count`?

Comment: @E.N.D because for [`vector( size_type count, const T& value, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) it will `Construct[s] the container with "count" copies of elements with value "value".`, so it will copy the element `A()` passed to the cosntructor 5 times.

Comment: @t.niese Thanks for resolving my doubt. You're super awesome!

Comment: `main` *must* return `int` explicitly.

Comment: Why do I need to call constructor explicitly? Imagine a more sophisitcated example: class Employe { public: static int unique_id_counter; int unique_id; int salary; Employe(int salary):salary(salary) { unique_id = ++unique_id_counter; }; In the above case we have to call non-default constructor to pass the salary. Yet we have to assign a different value for each unique_id automatically.